# Understanding DOM hierarchy in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm constantly running into strange things I don't understand with jQuery and DOM IDs and selectors. Usually I just work around them but I *really* wanna get this down once and for all. Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="accordionWrapper"><p><a class="expandall" href="#">Test</a></p></div>
```

I have a jQuery click function on an `<a>`:

```
//works fine
jQuery('a.expandall').click(function() {...whatever...});
```

But the following doesn't:

```
//fails
jQuery('#accordionWrapper p a.expandall').click(function() {...whatever...});
```

...which I don't get. Is this something I don't understand about CSS or jQuery or...?

Comment: Maybe you have more than one element with id `accordionWrapper` (which is not supported)?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, your understanding isn't wrong at all. Here's a JsBin (JsFiddle seems to be down) that shows your exact markup, and your exact jQuery code, all working.

http://jsbin.com/inuqez/4/edit

So, if you're experiencing problems with the second jQuery selector you gave, it's gotta be something else. If you give us more details, we may be able to help. Otherwise, just look at your code carefully and make sure that there aren't any obvious errors, like multiple elements with the same ID (as @Frederic mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
jQuery('div#accordianWrapper p a.expandall').click(...)
```

Comment: please explain why you think that will work better than the original

Comment: @user1063323: Actually, you don't. Using just the ID is a valid CSS selector. Look at my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I have always assumed that jQuery was pretty picky about referencing elements.. Learn something new every day.

Comment: it's worse than that - using `type#id` is actually less efficient than plain `#id`.

Comment: Well, that is what I started thinking. At very least it saves lines of code. I am reading about it now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The first way:

```
jQuery('a.expandall').click(function() {...whatever...});
```

...defines a click for any anchor element with class "expandall" that exists *anywhere in the DOM*.

The second way:

```
jQuery('#accordionWrapper p a.expandall').click(function() {...whatever...});
```

...defines a click for any anchor element with class "expandall" that is a descendant of a paragraph element that is a descendant of the element with `id="accordionWrapper"`. Note that the element type of "#accordionWrapper" doesn't matter since you haven't specified it.

I say "the element" with that id rather than "an element" with that id because if your html is valid there will be *only one* element with any given id. If you have repeated an id for multiple elements you'll find that (for most browsers) selecting by id will only return one of those elements (most commonly the first one).

Assuming your problem is due to re-use of ids, you would fix it by giving multiple like elements the same *class* rather than the same *id*.

Comment: op/p here. I really need to get me head round debugging better. My guess is that there's another function somewhere that's catching the 'click' -first-. How does one -quickly- determine if multiple click functions are 'bound' to the same ID... and in which order?

Comment: Oh yeah... can you have a click within a click? ie. If I have a click bound to an <li> can I create a distinct click function on an <a> -inside- the <li>?

Comment: @jchwebdev in Chrome's developer tools - right click the DOM element you want to check on your page and click Inspect Element. It'll be selected in the source in dev tools. On the right side, see the events under Event Listeners.

Comment: Thanks. I've gotten used to using FF, but more and more I get the impression that Chrome is better... faster... better tools for devs.